# Simple linux device driver does not appear in /dev

Tags: linux, kernel, device-driver

I've been writing a simple scull_dev device driver to learn about how to program kernel modules and I think I have one completely coded.

I can make it successfully, and I can call `sudo insmod scull.ko` without any problems, but the driver never appears in the linux `/dev/` folder.

I am now trying to implement `.ioctl`, but there is no file for me to open.  Isn't the correct way to use ioctl from a user space program to call it with the open fd of the "file" of your device driver? (Don't even really know what this means...)

The whole topic of device drivers is extremely, extremely confusing to me and the book I've been using is in my opinion complete garbage, so I am aware I probably have some major misconceptions here...

Comment: The old school way is to use mknod: `mknod /dev/scull0 c 254 0`

Comment: So does that create an instance of the driver? And the 0 is the major number, correct? So I need to know the correct major number for my scull driver for this to work properly?

Comment: That book is actually pretty good, but it is a little out-dated.  There is an explanation of what a device node is.  0 is the minor number.  The major numbers in Linux are normally assigned to types of drivers, so 254 is an arbitrary big number for the sample __skull__ device.  Your driver will get assigned to that node.

Comment: Also see _register_chrdev()_.

Comment: Yeah I just feel like the book assumes a greater level of knowledge than I have, yet I also feel like it is supposed to be the book for beginners on device drivers.

Anyways, i have a file created in /dev now, but my user space program that calls `open` is just returning a -1

Comment: ..err, yeah I have it setup to use the automatic method

Comment: your register_chrdev() params have to match the device node major.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  I'm using the `alloc_chrdev_region` method. So I'm assuming it got 254 like you said.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253434/questions-about-register-chrdev-region-in-linux-device-driver

Comment: Thanks.  That seems helpful, but I think my problem is elsewhere.  I'm using the dynamic major assignment method currently and am not getting any errors from it, but still hitting a roadblock here with trying to use `ioctl` - ie, `open("/dev/scull_dev", O_RDWR)` is returning a -1

Comment: Are the permissions on the device such that you can make read/write calls in your user context?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they weren't, and I don't know how to check that or change them.  Another thing I feel that book didn't cover so well... -__-

Comment: So would I be correct in stating that the `.open` function I setup in the `file_operations` structure is actually called when I call `open()` or `fopen()` on my device driver file (/dev/scull_dev)?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.  Same for ioctl(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using the alloc_chrdev_region method. So I'm assuming it got 254 ...

You should not assume something without reason. Print `*dev` returned by `alloc_chrdev_region()`, or use `register_chrdev(254, ...)` instead.

> my user space program that calls open is just returning a -1

No, it is not just returning -1, `open()` is also setting `errno` to an appropriate error number from which you can conveniently produce a message by using `perror()`.